# On AWS; Ubuntu; Not able to restart mysql using crontab

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cron, amazon-web-services

On AWS with Ubuntu; Not able to restart mysql using crontab :
I tried following commands in the script:

```
service mysql  start
 /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Errors I get are:

```
exec: 129: start: not found
/etc/init.d/mysql: 85: start: not found
exec: 129: restart: not found
```

All these works fine if I run from prompt; but fails from crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path was the problem. On command prompt I got $PATH; and then in crontab script ; I manually added this path like this. It works now.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```